# __zone_symbol_error while define a class in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 2.
So I just followed a tutorial, suddenly I got an error below.
My code is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component(
...
)

export class A {
....
}

export class AppComponent {
...
}
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError {**__zone_symbol_error**: Error: Unexpected value
>   'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule' at
>   SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError}

So I moved class A to the top of this file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class A {
....
}

@Component(
...
)

export class AppComponent {
...
}
```

So it works well.

But I wish to know how to fixed this issue.

Comment: @Component decorator will be applied only to the class which follows immediatley.

Comment: that is fine but why do you need to have two classes at single place. that is modularized export it and if required just import it there.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare

export class A {
....
}

Below

export class AppComponent {
...
}

So that it will not throw error.

Reason: Each component must has only one class that can be only exported

Comment: The component name which you imported in AppModule, the particular named class only needs to be declared first